# jquery-ajax : getting server xml

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get XML response from webservice like:

```
function xmlparser() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'application/xml',
        success: function (xml) {
            result = $(xml).find("post").text();
            text = result;
            return text;
        },
        error: function (xml) {
            alert(xml);
            alert(xml.status + ' ' + xml.statusText);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

but i'm always get a error function  ( [object Object] , 200 OK )

XML :

```
     <posts><post>Adolf : get more minerals | </post></posts>
```

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `dataType` is not valid for `xml`, change `dataType: 'application/xml',` to `dataType: 'xml'`, and try

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `dataType: 'application/xml',` just use `dataType: 'xml',` also it is better to write a header at PHP side, which will determine the response as XML `header('Content-type: application/xml');`